# Is not calling [super init] in the init method ever correct?

Tags: objective-c, winobjc

In Microsoft's WinObjC UIApplication.mm file (at https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit/UIApplication.mm) the `init` method is implemented for both `UIApplication` and `WOCDisplayMode`.

Neither class' `init` method calls `[super init]`, or any method from that family of methods that would eventually result in a call to `[super init]`. I've never seen this before, apart from the initialization of `NSProxy` objects.

I've reproduced the implementation as of this writing of `WOCDisplayMode` below for reference.

```
-(instancetype) init
{
    _fixedWidth = 320.0f;
    _fixedHeight = 480.0f;
    _fixedAspectRatio = 0.0f;
    _magnification = 1.0f;
    _autoMagnification = TRUE;
    _sizeUIWindowToFit = TRUE;
    _operationMode = WOCOperationModePhone;
    return self;
}
```

It seems to me that this could create a number of problems; for example, if one of the superclasses of `UIApplication`, like `UIResponder`, at some point overrode `init` itself, and set up internal state that future method calls depended on.

Why might the implementor have elected not to call `[super init]`? Is this ever a justifiable decision? Is it ever the correct one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This definitely seems like an error on behalf of the author(s) of those classes.

`NSProxy` does not call `[super init]` because it is an abstract superclass and **does not** inherit from `NSObject`.

Since their implementation of `UIApplication` inherits from `UIResponder`, and `WOCDisplayMode` inherits from `NSObject` they should be calling `[super init]` in these classes.

According to the documentation on [Object Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW58):

> The requirement to invoke the superclass’s initializer as the first
>   action is important. Recall that an object encapsulates not only the
>   instance variables defined by its class but the instance variables
>   defined by all of its ancestor classes. By invoking the initializer of
>   super first, you help to ensure that the instance variables defined by
>   classes up the inheritance chain are initialized first. The immediate
>   superclass, in its initializer, invokes the initializer of its
>   superclass, which invokes the main init... method of its superclass,
>   and so on (see Figure 6-1). The proper order of initialization is
>   critical because the later initializations of subclasses may depend on
>   superclass-defined instance variables being initialized to reasonable
>   values.

I would recommend logging it as an issue on the project.